# How to SELECT last row of every hour?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I have a table (in database) with one minute data in each row.
Like this:

```
Date_time            Value

2018-11-01 10:58:00  189.0
2018-11-01 10:59:00  189.0
2018-11-01 11:00:00  189.19
2018-11-01 11:01:00  189.19
2018-11-01 11:02:00  189.35
...
2018-11-02 13:57:00  192.38
2018-11-02 13:58:00  192.41
2018-11-02 14:01:00  192.35
2018-11-02 14:02:00  192.35
...
2018-11-06 15:50:00  196.89
2018-11-06 15:51:00  196.86
2018-11-06 16:00:00  196.77
2018-11-06 16:01:00  196.69
2018-11-06 16:02:00  196.64
```

I need to SELECT last row of every hour in table. The difficulty here is that it is not known what minute will be the last in an hour.

Comment: why are you tagging this both postgresql and sqllite, which db are you using?

Comment: Now i using SQLite. But if it is not possible to resolve the issue on SQLite, then I can go to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

```
 https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html
```

SQLite supports window functions. You can therefore easily enumerate the resultset like:

```
SELECT date_time, value
     , row_number() over (partition by DATE(date_time), HOUR(date_time)
                          order by dt desc) as rn
FROM T
```

I'm not sure what date functions there are, so you might have to change those. Now, since we ordered them in descending order, we can just pick the first one:

```
SELECT date_time, value
FROM (
    SELECT date_time, value
         , row_number() over (partition by DATE(date_time), HOUR(date_time)
                              order by dt desc) as rn
    FROM T
) AS X
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Date_time), Value FROM T GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y%m%d%H', Date_time);
```

The [STRFTIME](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) call creates a string to represent the hour (without minutes and seconds), and the [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) takes advantage of an **SQLite-specific** behavior.

> Special processing occurs occurs when the aggregate function is either
>   min() or max(). Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, b, max(c) FROM tab1 GROUP BY a;
> ```
>
> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate
>   query, all bare columns in the result set take values from the input
>   row which also contains the minimum or maximum. So in the query above,
>   the value of the "b" column in the output will be the value of the "b"
>   column in the input row that has the largest "c" value. There is still
>   an ambiguity if two or more of the input rows have the same minimum or
>   maximum value or if the query contains more than one min() and/or
>   max() aggregate function. Only the built-in min() and max() functions
>   work this way.